# C webserver not returning file with GET request. Error: 'curl: (52) Empty reply from server'

Tags: c, sockets, webserver

I'm trying to start out with a very basic C webserver program. I tried following along this example on YouTube — https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2HrYIl6GpYg. So my code is nearly word for word. The web server is supposed to return an index.html file with the GET request. But I am only getting the error `curl: (52) Empty reply from server` when I run `curl --http0.9 --output - 'http://localhost:8080/index.html'`.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int PORT;
    int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(8080);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));

    listen(s, 10);

    int client_fd = accept(s, 0, 0);

    char buffer[256] = {0};
    recv(client_fd, buffer, 256, 0);

    // GET /file.html .....
    char* f = buffer + 5;
    printf("%s", f);
    *strchr(f, ' ') = 0;
    printf("After strch:\n%s", f);
    int opened_fd = open(f, O_RDONLY);
    send(client_fd, &opened_fd, 256, NULL);
    //sendfile(opened_fd, client_fd, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    close(opened_fd);
    close(client_fd);
    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: How do you know that the creator of the video isn't some raving lunatic or content farmer who only cares about ad revenue and not whether or not the code actually works? Can you trust their code?

Comment: Your post talks about C language, so why the C++ tag?  They are distinct languages, for example C++ has `std::list` and `std::vector` and C language doesn't.  C language doesn't have inheritance nor exceptions.  Remove the C++ tag unless you are mixing the two languages (because of C++ overloading capabilities, you'll need to deal with function name mangling).

Comment: They show that it works in the video. @user4581301

Comment: Sorry, removed the tag @ThomasMatthews

Comment: Important note about network programming: NEVER ignore the return codes. They all provide important information and often vital information the code will not work reliably without. For example, `send` doesn't guarantee that it actually sends what you wrote into it. It promises to write what it can into the send buffer associated with the socket and tell you how much it wrote. It doesn't even ensure that what it wrote into the buffer was sent to or received by the other side. Network code is really finicky, full of error checking and handing, and loops to keep trying until it is successful.

Comment: Enable more warnings. All the warnings. And treat them as errors. e.g. what are the parameters to `send()`? It expects a buffer of bytes. You're sending a file descriptor.

Comment: Didn't make it through the ad preceding the video, but the code in this question is ... terrible. If it's what's in the video, you're doomed. I recommend instead a trusted resource: https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/ Learn how to write robust networking code, then start working on advanced stuff like simple webservers.

Comment: The most constructive thing I can add is to reiterate my recommendation that you learn from [beej](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/). He covers the basics and does it in clean and understandable language. He doesn't cut corners and leave you wondering where things broke. Because you checked all of the result codes and made sure everything worked, and if it didn't you know where and why.

Comment: Following through on @pmacfarlane 's comment, unfortunately this falls into a hole. Because `send` takes the data buffer as a `void` pointer and in C a pointer to anything converts to a `void` pointer there is no warning. You might get a warning about using a `NULL` where an integer was requested, but that's about it.  You can't just open a file and `send` it to the socket, that tries to send the file handle--a number that represents the file. You need to read the file into a buffer, an array of suitable size, and then `send` the buffer.

Comment: cURL complains about *Empty reply from server* because you didn't successfully send the file. You sent the number representing the file and another 250-or-so bytes of garbage that happened to be after the that number in memory.

Comment: Handy tool: Get a copy of wireshark if it's not already installed. Use wireshark to listen in on the network connection between cURL and your program and take a look at the data being sent back and forth. It's a real eye-opener sometimes.

Comment: And apologies if I'm coming on strong. It's not you. It's not because you are new and asking a question full of bad ideas. it's years of cleaning up after idiots posting crap that barely runs once and gave new programmers like you those bad ideas. There is a whole industry of <expletive deleted>heads capitalizing on the fact that new programmers don't know how to tell that they're reading garbage.

Comment: No its all good. All this stuff is helpful thanks, you pointed me in a direction i can look into, thanks. First port of call is to look into writing the file into a buffer then using that in the send function. @user4581301

Comment: `send(client_fd, &opened_fd, 256, NULL);` - this is your code and it's completely wrong.

Comment: Will converting opened_fd into a char buffer fix this? @273K

Comment: The TL;DR: `curl` expects the server to honor the `http` _protocol_ and `html`. It expects _keywords_. The server does _not_ have this. So, to test, you'd need to write your own client program, or use `ncat` or `telnet`.

Comment: Also, the video, instead of using `htons` hardwires the port address in hex. That's _bad_ programming from someone who hasn't a clue. Hit "Unsubscribe" ...

Comment: Thanks for the info @CraigEstey, its looking more and more likely that im better off abandoning this chunk of code and go back to the drawing board. The one thing that drew me to this code is that it stepped out the 'process' if you could call it that, get your linked list, bind the socket, listen for a connection, spit out a result. Other code examples ive found are a lot more bloated, i wanted to start with trying to understand the core functions.

Comment: There are _many_ [good] examples on SO. With a bit of narcissism, here are some of my SO answers: [thread function doesn't terminate until Enter is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72341219/5382650), [executing commands via sockets with popen()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35446058/5382650), [multi-threaded file transfer with socket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37506686/5382650), [Trouble with converting single threaded HTTP server into multithreaded using pthreads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61826887/5382650)

Comment: You cannot convert the file descriptor into a buffer. You need to read the file into the buffer. `char buffer[SOME_RESONABLE_SIZE]; int dataread= fread(buffer, SOME_RESONABLE_SIZE, opened_fd);`. You then test `dataread` for error conditions and either correct the errors and try again or loop calls to `send` until all `dataread` bytes are written to the socket, checking for and handling errors as you go. This code is guaranteed to look bloated because if it isn't it'll only work if you get lucky. Note you should also loop calls to `fread` to ensure you get all of the file.

Comment: I'm going to push [beej](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/) again because his stuff is about as simple as it gets and still be counted on to work. The core functions count on you to read, understand and handle all of the diagnostics they return. In other languages you'll have simpler interfaces that hide more of the checking behind exceptions and similar mechanisms, and there are C libraries that try to simplify the interface by handling a lot of the checking for you, but ultimately C follows a philosophy of you only get what you asked for, and if you don't check there will be no check.

Answer (score 0):

HMMMMMMM.... You don't explain well what you are trying to do. But as I can guess... (I will assume that you have received what you say in the comment, this is `GET /file.html HTML/1.0\r\n` and more headers.  About your question

> Where am I going wrong?

The main issue is: You need to check what happened in one step to proceed to the next.  If you try all steps to be correct on the first time, you are going wrong.  Do error checking, this is the main issue, (look at the shown code as example) Remember, one step at a time (as I did :))

1. you search the buffer at offset 5 (the position of the letter `'f'`) for the occurence of the first space, and put a 0 there (despite you don't check errors anywhere)  This will has the effect of cutting/terminating your buffer at the first space encountered later, leaving only the string `file.html`.
2. Then you, try to open the file `file.html` in the process' current directory (not known, by the way).  This is probably an error as you will probably have no file named `file.html` in your current working directory.
3. You act blindly thinking that everything has gone ok, trying to send the file over the socket descriptor, as you don't check for errors anywhere in the code.
4. Finally and this is an actual error.  The call

```
    send(client_fd, &opened_fd, 256, NULL);
```

is incorrect, as you pass it in the second parameter, the address of the file descriptor, and not the address of a buffer where the data to be sent is contained, and that you should fill with characters from the file, you should read (in the buffer if you like, but you have it filled with the file name, the command, the http version, etc.  As you don't check errors, the problem gets undetected.  IMHO, you have used `sendfile()` system call and you have believed that with `send` the interface is the same.  But I can be wrong.

After each system call you make, you should do the following (I show you an example):

```
/* you had better, if below you use sizeof buffer, instead of the
 * magic number 256, that you will have to change, in addititon, if
 * you happen to change the actual buffer size, in the declaration
 */
int rd = recv(client_fd, buffer, 256, 0);
if (rd < 0) {
    perror("recv");
    exit(1);
}
```

(well, it is very important that you check the actual number of bytes read, as coming from the network you are never sure that the buffer has been completely filled, and if it is, it will never be string `'\0'` terminated, so you cannot use any of the `str` prefixed functions)

This approach will end the program at the point of failure and you will get a message of what happened.  Of course, this cannot be done in a real server, but as an example to debug, it suffices.

Don't assume that you will receive a `' '` character in the input.  A malicious client could send you trash, just to make your program fail and your service interrupted.  If that is not the case, you will check the full `buffer` for a space and beyond (as `recv` doesn't terminate the received string) and this will result in undefined behaviour (indeed you have what is widely known a *buffer overflow*).  Most notably your program could crash.

If my guess is correct, the observed result will be correct too.  You will receive nothing because you send nothing on the socket.  For an HTTP server, sending nothing as result of an exchange is a very unpolite doing.  As you close the connection, `curl` will show you the message it is showing.  It happens because for `curl` this is an HTTP protocol violation, and so it complains.

If you are not recommended in that Youtube video to check every call you make to the system for errors, then you need to change your teacher.  Go to an academy or to university, to learn programming, don't use Youtube as learning place.  Is is cheaper, but you know, cheaper doesn't mean necessarily good.  Mainly because there will be a time that you feel perfectly capable to deal professionally in programming, and you will be one more of the huge amounts of intruders that publish videos in Youtube, claiming they are making a good job teaching people to do something they don't know how to, and making this business more a nigthmare for professionals, than other thing.

Below is a corrected version of your code (I don't claim it to be perfect, even good, anyway) that you can use as starting point, it responds correctly  (or almost) to `curl` and handles appropiately some of the common errors you can have (a full http server requires far more code):

### pru.c

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BIND_PORT 8086

size_t send_response(
        FILE *in,
        FILE *out,
        char *vers,
        int   retcode,
        char *messg,
        struct stat *inode)
{
    time_t now;
    time(&now);
    char temp[32],
        *dumb = temp;
    ctime_r(&now, temp);

    size_t ret_val = 0;
    ssize_t n = fprintf(out,
            "%s %03u %s\r\n"
            "Content-type: text/plain\r\n"
            "Content-length: %lu\r\n"
            "Date: %s\r\n"
            "\r\n",
            vers, retcode, messg,
            inode ? inode->st_size : 0,
            strsep(&dumb, "\n\r"));
    if (n < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "printf: %s\n",
                strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (in && inode) {
        size_t sz = inode->st_size;
        int c;
        while((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF && sz--)
            fputc(c, out);
    }
    return ret_val;
} /* send_response */


char *strupper(char *in)
{
    for (char *p = in; *p; p++)
        *p = toupper(*p);
    return in;
} /* strupper */

int main()
{
    int PORT;
    int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (s < 0) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(BIND_PORT);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    int res = bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    if (res < 0) {
        perror("bind");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    res = listen(s, 10);
    if (res < 0) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int client_fd = accept(s, 0, 0);
    if (client_fd < 0) {
        perror("accept");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* now we have somebody connected, let's parse input */

    char buffer[256];
    int read_in = read(client_fd, buffer, sizeof buffer);
    if (read_in < 0) {
        perror("read");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (read_in == sizeof buffer) {
        read_in--;            /* assume we discard the last character */
        buffer[read_in] = 0;  /* to allow use of str*() funtions */
    }

    // GET /file.html .....
    char *buf_ptr = buffer;
    char *method = strsep(&buf_ptr, " ");
    if (!method) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No command received, aborting\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    strupper(method);
    char *uri = strsep(&buf_ptr, " ");
    if (!uri) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Bad syntax, no file present\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    char *http_version = strsep(&buf_ptr, "\r\n");
    if (!http_version) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "Bad syntax, no HTTP version token\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    strupper(http_version);
    if (   strcmp(http_version, "HTTP/1.0")
        && strcmp(http_version, "HTTP/1.1"))
    {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "Bad version: %s, cannot process\n",
                http_version);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    /* now we have http request valid, check other things
     * and create a buffered output FILE * descriptor to
     * do text output. */
    FILE *out = fdopen(client_fd, "w");
    if (strcmp(method, "GET")) { /* if method different than GET */
        fprintf(stderr,
                "Bad method: %s, cannot process\n",
                method);
        /* from this point onwards, we need to send an appropiately
         * formatted HTTP response to the client. Check below for a 
         * reference to HTTP protocol */
        send_response(NULL, out, http_version,
                501, "Not implemented", NULL);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    /* translate uri to file */
    uri++; /* advance the pointer to eliminate the leading / */

    FILE *in = fopen(uri, "r");
    if (!in) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "fopen: %s: %s\n",
                uri, strerror(errno));
        switch (errno) {
        case ENOTDIR: case ENOENT:
            send_response(NULL, out, http_version,
                    404, "Not found", NULL);
            break;
        default:
            send_response(NULL, out, http_version,
                    403, "Forbidden", NULL);
            break;
        }
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); /* this will close/fclose all */
    }
    struct stat ino;
    res = fstat(fileno(in), &ino);
    if (res < 0) {
        send_response(NULL, out, http_version,
            404, "Not found", NULL);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    send_response(in, out, http_version, 200, "OK", &ino);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
} /* main */
```

(*) Check [HTTP Protocol RFC-7230--7240](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230)

The above example, when run against `curl`, it produces:

```
$ curl -v --http1.1 -o pru2.c http://europa:8086/pru.c
* processing: http://europa:8086/pru.c
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 192.168.1.107:8086...
* Connected to europa (192.168.1.107) port 8086
> GET /pru.c HTTP/1.1
> Host: europa:8086
> User-Agent: curl/8.2.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-type: text/plain
< Content-length: 4586
< Date: Fri Feb  2 13:31:21 2024
< 
{ [4586 bytes data]
100  4586  100  4586    0     0  2326k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 4478k
* Connection #0 to host europa left intact
```

and the two files (`pru.c` and `pru2.c` compare equal, the first before transmission the one being after trasmitted)

On looking for unexistent file, the output is:

```
$ curl -v --http1.1 http://europa:8086/inexistent.html
* processing: http://europa:8086/inexistent.html
*   Trying 192.168.1.107:8086...
* Connected to europa (192.168.1.107) port 8086
> GET /inexistent.html HTTP/1.1
> Host: europa:8086
> User-Agent: curl/8.2.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not found
< Content-type: text/plain
< Content-length: 0
< Date: Fri Feb  2 13:35:23 2024
< 
* Connection #0 to host europa left intact
```